# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: verdaccio

Getting heap limit allocation error. Need a clarity on how can we get through this using verdaccio config

Checked node config max-old-space-size can fix this. But want a way to fix this using verdaccio

Comment: I have the same issue with VS Code and the Vue Semantic Server (I guess this is from the Volar extension).

Answer (score 0):

Set `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096` environment variable (the size may depend on your available memory).

If you are running verdaccio using systemd, add

```
Environment="NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096"
```

to the unit file, [Service] section.